# requestCode code is returning same value either change the you check option for gps or not

Tags: android, android-activity, resultset

I am calling the following method:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
startActivityForResult(intent, GPS_LOC);
```

but on onActivityResultas below method

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode != -1) {
           switch (requestCode) {
              case GPS_LOC:
                userData();
               break;
            }
         }  
     }
```

it's "requestCode" and "resultCode" returning same value either you "on" the gps setting or returning without doing "on". I don't want to call userData(); when user didn't turn "on" gps setting. Please look into matter

Comment: What is the value of GPS_LOC?

Comment: protected static final int GPS_LOC =5;

Comment: So when you run your code, resultCode = what? and requestCode = what?

Comment: it's giving resultCode "5" and requestCode "0" in both the cases. either I am doing nothing or doing activity like "on" the gps setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you cannot start the Activity:

```
android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS
```

for a result.

Therefore your requestCode is never returned from the activity.

Ask yourself why you want to start this for a result? Is it to check if they have turned on the GPS? If it is so, when the activity returns just check it again. If it is for another reason I don't think you grasp what startActivityForResult's use is.

Related question:
[getting-back-from-location-to-my-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730120/getting-back-from-security-location-to-my-application)

Comment: Actually, I want to turn "on" gps setting if it is "off" and then proceed further for my app. If it is still "off" and user did not turn "on" gps setting then it need to close the app and don't proceed app further. Could you please help me how it could be implemented. Thanking you...

Comment: Yes so do what your doing, then when you get back, don't check the resultCode just check the LocationManager if GPS is enabled, if it isn't tell the user it is disabled and call finish();

Comment: great, it's going to help me...:)

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you mean and I had the same issue several days ago.

In you case, you should not use onActivityResult since the location source setting activity will never set the result code.

In order to achieve what you want, you should do something in your onResume() method. Once the GPS location source setting activity finished, your onResume() method will be called. So you just check the GPS on or off in onResume.

Pay attention, onResume will be called after onCreate when you first start the app. So you should decide onResume is called after onCreate or after the GPS setting activity.

Below is the a sample code

```
 void onCreate(){
    //do something 
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(intent);}

 void onResume(){
    if (firstTime){
      // do something
       firstTime = false;
    }
    else{ // it's from GPS setting activity
     //check your gps again with your logic here
    }
 }
```