# can't return to activity after System settings intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, settings

In my applicattion i need to go to de settings activity of the phone to activate GPS and want to return to my application using this code code:

`Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivityForResult(intent);`

but when I used it I couldn't return to my app. when I pressed back so I tried this :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

then I called all types of result in this code

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent x){
    if(requestCode == 0){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
            Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            b.setText("ON");
            b.setTextColor(0xff2d9ede);
            Intent k = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), serve.class);
            startService(k);    
        }
    }

    if(resultCode == RESULT_FIRST_USER){
        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setText("ON");
        b.setTextColor(0xff2d9ede);
        Intent k = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), serve.class);
        startService(k);    
    }

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setText("ON");
        b.setTextColor(0xff2d9ede);
        Intent k = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), serve.class);
        startService(k);    
    }
}
}
```

but this also didn't work ..The same happened (didn't go back to my app).. any Ideas ??      ... thanks in advance

here is the code of the whole activity:

```
public class Layout2Activity extends Activity {
static String username4 ;
private static final int DIALOG_ALERT = 10;
private static final int DIALOG_ALERT2 = 8;
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    switch (keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
        showDialog(DIALOG_ALERT);

        return true;
    }

}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;


boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);
     ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);


    SharedPreferences name = getSharedPreferences("user", MODE_PRIVATE);
    username4 = name.getString("name"+Passwardentry.usernomain,"Admin");

    SharedPreferences p = getSharedPreferences("user", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String number = p.getString("mob"+Passwardentry.usernomain, "please assign no.");

    SharedPreferences last = getSharedPreferences("user", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = last.edit();
    edit.putString("last number", number);
    edit.commit();

    TextView k = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    k.setText(username4);

    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    t.setText(number);
    if (serve.isStarted) {
        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setText("ON");
        b.setTextColor(0xff2d9ede);
        //TextView n = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        // n.setTextColor(0x7fff00); leh el 2alwan mesh zahra ??
        //n.setText("  On  ");

    } else {
        //TextView n = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        // n.setTextColor(0xff0000);
        //n.setText("  Off  ");
        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setText("OFF");
        b.setTextColor(Color.rgb( 139,137,137   ));
    }



}

  public void userchange(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), setuserc.class);
    startActivity(i);

}

   public void servicebutton(View V) {

      if (serve.isStarted) {
        //TextView n = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        // n.setTextColor(0xff0000);
        //n.setText("  Off  ");
        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setText("OFF");
        b.setTextColor(Color.rgb( 139,137,137   ));
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), serve.class);
        stopService(i);

    } else {
        //TextView n = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        // n.setTextColor(0x7fff00);
        //n.setText("  On  ");


        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)    getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if(isGPSEnabled && isNetworkEnabled){

        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setText("ON");
        b.setTextColor(0xff2d9ede);
        Intent k = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), serve.class);
        startService(k);}
            else {
                showDialog(DIALOG_ALERT2);



            } 

    }

}

  public void readingsbutt(View V) {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Readings.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_intro, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    // int group1 = 1;
    // MenuItem infoBtn = menu.add(group1,1,1,"About");
    // MenuItem mn = menu.add(group1, 2, 2, "arm");
    // mn.setIcon(R.drawable.set);
    // infoBtn.setIcon(R.drawable.set);

     //int group2=2; 
    // MenuItem appSettings = menu.add(group2,3,2,"Application Settings");
    // appSettings.setIcon(R.drawable.set);



     return true;
}

  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_settings) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), settings.class);
        startActivity(i);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
    }
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.help) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), help.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.about) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Info.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
     //switch(item.getItemId()) {
    // case 1:
    //    break;
    //  case 2:
    //    break;
    // }

    return true;
}



   @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_ALERT:
      // Create out AlterDialog
      Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
      builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to Quit ?");
      builder.setCancelable(true);
      builder.setPositiveButton("NO", new OkOnClickListener());
      builder.setNegativeButton("Yes", new CancelOnClickListener());
      AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
      dialog.show();


    case DIALOG_ALERT2:
          // Create out AlterDialog
          Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
          builder2.setMessage("No location service available please activate network and satellite GPS ");
          builder2.setCancelable(true);
          builder2.setPositiveButton("Cancel", new OkOnClickListener2());
          builder2.setNegativeButton("Settings", new CancelOnClickListener2());
          AlertDialog dialog2 = builder2.create();
          dialog2.show();
    }
    return super.onCreateDialog(id);
  }

    private final class CancelOnClickListener implements
      DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        setResult(0);
        finish();
        System.exit(0);// /el 2aaady


    }}
    private final class OkOnClickListener implements
     DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {



  }
    }

    private final class CancelOnClickListener2 implements
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);



   }}
  private final class OkOnClickListener2 implements
 DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {



}
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent x){
    if(requestCode == 0){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
            Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            b.setText("ON");
            b.setTextColor(0xff2d9ede);
            Intent k = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), serve.class);
            startService(k);    
        }
    }

    if(resultCode == RESULT_FIRST_USER){
        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setText("ON");
        b.setTextColor(0xff2d9ede);
        Intent k = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), serve.class);
        startService(k);    
    }

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setText("ON");
        b.setTextColor(0xff2d9ede);
        Intent k = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), serve.class);
        startService(k);    
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: What view did you see after closing the system-settings, if not your app.

Comment: main menu or whatever other active app

Comment: @YoussefElHemali : plz add full Activity code with question to get more help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below works for me.

```
package com.example.test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
boolean firstTime = true;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.i("test", "onCreate");
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS); 
        startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    Log.i("test", "onResume");
    if (firstTime){
    Log.i("test", "it's the first time");
    firstTime = false;
    }

    else{
    Log.i("test", "it's not the first time");

    }

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on **Android 7.0 Nougat**.

The solution was to simply add to manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
```

Then after closing the Settings activity my calling activity came back.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you mean and I had the same issue several days ago. I also answered the similar question at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324608/requestcode-code-is-returning-same-value-either-change-the-you-check-option-for/15558436#15558436)

I just post my answer here again.

In you case, you should not use onActivityResult since the location source setting activity will never set the result code for you.

In order to achieve what you want, you should do something in your onResume() method. Once the GPS location source setting activity finished, your onResume() method will be called. So you just check the GPS on or off in onResume.

Pay attention, onResume will be called after onCreate when you first started the app. So you should decide onResume is called after onCreate or after the GPS setting activity.

Below is the a sample code

```
void onCreate(){
    //do something 
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(intent);
 }

void onResume(){
    if (firstTime){
  // do something
    firstTime = false;
    }
    else{ // it's from GPS setting activity
     //check your gps again with your logic here
    }
 }
```

Comment: sry , this didn't work , the same result . left the app. for good & didn't return

Comment: When the setting activity finished, Was your onResume( ) called ?

Comment: note:tried the code 2 times first time crashed & required that onResume would be super so i tried this line super.onResume(); .. would it make any difference ?? sry I'm new to android ..any way thanks for Your concern

Comment: First make sure that when the setting activity returns, your onResume() method is called. According to my understanding towards Android, it should be called in your case. Try to print something in onResume().

Comment: made 2 toasts 1 for the resume after  firstTime = false; named resume1 this 1 worked the other after else called resume2 but didn't apear

Comment: Ennnn, so strange, I've no idea now since I can't run your code directly. Maybe you can do some simple experiment. Only one button in this app, and click the button will trigger the setting app, observe the app's behavior

Comment: tryed it but didn't return too

Comment: going to try it in the location service itself