# How to return to my app after sending the user to settings with an intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to figure a way to how to return the user to my app after they enabled location services automatically without the need for the user to press the back button.
I check if the location services is enabled like that:

```
if( !locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
            alertForNoLocationEnabled();
        }else {

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new MyLocationListener());
        }
private void alertForNoLocationEnabled() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.network_not_found_title);  // network not found
    builder.setMessage(R.string.network_not_found_message); // Want to enable?
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            toggleSwipeRefreshLayoutsOff();
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            toggleSwipeRefreshLayoutsOff();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.show();
}
```

and after the user turns on the location services I want automatically the user to be taken back to my app and not pressing the back button.
Please, anyone who has an idea to share it.

[image]

Comment: I've been wondering too. seems like you just have to let the user navigate back naturally.

Comment: Actually You could accomplish what you want with a WakefulBroadcastReceiver, but it would be quite an extensive solution opposed to just letting the user navigate back

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can't return to activity after System settings intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618423/cant-return-to-activity-after-system-settings-intent)

Comment: The concept would be to send an intent to your broadcast receiver upon sending the user to the location page. And then have a thread constantly check (while loop) as to whether locations are enabled or not. When they enable them, the app relaunches itself from the wakefulbroadcastreceiver

Comment: @KoalaKoalified that sounds a bit complicated

Comment: Yeah an IntentService may also be able to do the job, but in the same concept. All vs just having the user press back

Comment: I know that it could be too much effort for something that is so simple but it is very handy from user point of view. That is why I want to do it.

Comment: Honestly , a user might feel confused or uncomfortable if they auto return to your app after flipping on the location service. Where have you ever seen that behavior ?

Comment: @Owls You could be right. I have seen that behaviour when you are installing Swiftkey and there are 3 steps that you have to go through to enable the keyboard. 1. Enable SwiftKey 2. Select SwiftKey 3. Get better predictions. After you select, for example, the first option you are taken to the settings where you have to enable the keyboard and immediately you do that  you are taken back to the 3 step process automatically.

Comment: @GeorgiKoemdzhiev Oh. Welp nvm, I had never seen it before so I was thinking it might feel foreign/unexpected. SwiftKey is super popular though so it definitely isn't that bizarre.

Comment: @Owls yes, it is very popular and I thought it will be fairly easy to implement the same behaviour to my app as well but I guess it is not that simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work.

```
 builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        toggleSwipeRefreshLayoutsOff();

    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
       public void run() {
         long fortySecondsFromNow = System.currentTimeMillis() + 40*1000
         while((System.curremtTimeMillis < fortySecondsFromNow)
              && !locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER))) {
             Thread.sleep(300);
          } 
        if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER){
          Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
          intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
          intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
          startActivity(intent);
          //Do what u want
           } 

        });

        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: @Owis that did the job perfectly! Thank you so much! This method will work for 40 seconds, though - I tested it. After 40 seconds the user has to use the back button to get back to the app but that is easily fixable by increasing the time if needed. Thank you again!

Comment: @Georgi No problem Georgi !  You can easily mess with the thread sleep too.  When this takes you back to your app, is the Activity stack fine/normal ? Im just curious, didnt test it myself yet haha. As far as I know , it should go back to that Activity if it is already in the stack. It shouldnt make a new one.

Comment: @Owis I can't tell you if the stack is fine because my app consists of one main  activity with a view pager with 3 sliding taps. :D

Comment: @GeorgiKoemdzhiev Haha well as long as that works I suppose everything is okay !

Comment: Yes, it does the job just fine. I just made it very easy (thanks to u) for my lazy customers :D